# How can i get the case and user input into a tee

Tags: bash-scripting

I work in support and am creating a script that allows a user to quickly gather information for diagnostic reasons.

I have multiple searches and choose to use the case method inside a .sh

```
main() {
#What we looking for?
echo "Whats broken? ( Key , Level, Bot, LPN, Variant, Starvation, Disconnects"
echo "entering \"helplist\" will print and list of available choices"
echo "Enter quit to quit or just control+c =-)"
read broken

#push to lowercase :p
broken2="${broken,,}"
#makes log files



case "$broken2" in
    "stuck task")
        echo "Task Number?"
        read -r taskid
        grep --color=auto "id=$taskid" "$engine"/TaskAssignment.txt | tee ~/$broken2.task$taskid.txt
        ;;

        
esac
printf "\n\n"
main
}
main
```

The tee itself works fine but I'd like to be able to generate the file based on the case and the argument passed into it.

How can you get the value of the case into the tee command read $case ?

Comment: What did you use for the case statement? If it's not in a variable, then make it so, and reuse the variable?

Comment: Such an easy oversight... Trying now.

Comment: Didn't work. Can't get the code to format right in the comments so re-edited original post to include original read

Comment: I'd presume (from the snippet you've provided) that `$broken2` contains a space, so because you didn't quote the arguments to `tee`, you'll have two files - `~/stuck` and `./task.task$taskid.txt`. It's also wise to use the `${var}` syntax instead of `$var` when building a string, to be more precise variable naming.

Comment: Got it!
Two lines edited in the file
`case ${broken2} in`
`tee ~/"${broken2}".$taskid.txt`

Comment: Great! Quote the whole thing (i.e: `"~/${broken2}.task${taskid}.txt"`), and feel free to submit an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

By reading the case as a variable it will be passed down into the case itself

Case is stored as broken2 but since some cases will contain multiple words we wrap them in brackets

`case ${broken2} in`

`grep --color=auto "id="$taskid"" $engine/TaskAssignment.txt | tee -a ~/"${broken2}".$taskid.txt`

Running the script with `./tool.sh`
broken2 was fed `stuck task`
taskid was fed `762540`
file output `stuck task.762540.txt`